# display data from json to html using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a simple block I want to display buttons from JSON.

Here is my JSON movies:

```
{
    "movies": [
        {
            "title": "Mena",
            "movieid": "1",
            "movie_url": "videos\/mena.mp4",
            "buttons": [
                {
                    "left": 556,
                    "top": 231,
                    "start_time": 5.44,
                    "end_time": 6.76,
                    "width": 162,
                    "height": 73,
                    "buttonid": "1",
                    "label": "No"
                },
                {
                    "left": 200,
                    "top": 200,
                    "start_time": 5.56,
                    "end_time": 6.56,
                    "width": 162,
                    "height": 100,
                    "buttonid": "2",
                    "label": "Yes"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my JS for displaying buttons to the DOM:

```
    for(var j=0; j<movies.length; j++){
        for(a=0; a< movies[j].buttons.length; a++){
                                    
            var videobtns = $("<div class='video-btns'></div>")
            $(videobtns).html(movie[j].buttons.buttoid);
            $("#video-container").append(videobtns);
        }
    }
});
```

**My solution is not working as expected**. I had many for loops.

I would like to display these buttons with all its attributes (top, left, width, height, buttonid, label etc.);

What do I need to change to get this working?

Comment: What are `movie` and `buttoid` ?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I have provided a json , I have one movie so far , there is no two movies as you can see in my json,

Comment: @LeeTaylor there is one movie with name 'mena' and contains two buttons  which have attribute buttonid,  now I want to display these buttons to the dom.

Comment: OK. This clearly isn't even close to working code. You don't show your declaration of `movie` and you have a typo in your code `buttoid`...So the code you have would show **zero** buttons

Comment: Sure you aren't going through that loop twice? Code shown won't create 4 buttons by itself

Comment: @9964622, your code [does not do](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/Lhbcsrvy/) what you're saying it does. Which means your question is unanswerable, because you're not showing the relevant code.

Comment: @charlietfl ur right.

Comment: As a side note, I don't think `$(videobtns).html(movies[j].buttons.buttoid);` does what you think it does. Because it doesn't produce any HTML whatsoever.

Comment: I've [played a bit](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/Lhbcsrvy/) with your json. "Doesn't work as expected" doesn't mean anything unless you explain the expectation unequivocally, at which point saying "doesn't work as expected" is stating the obvious, therefore useless.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems with your code, for instance `buttoid` should be `buttonid` and instead of `$(videobtns).html(movie[j].buttons.buttoid);` it needs to be something like `movies[j].buttons[a].buttonid` because `movie` is not a variable and you need to specify the `buttons` array index to access the `buttonid` property.

I don't see why this code would produce 4 buttons with the given set of data beside it being executed twice.

```js
var json = {
    "movies": [
        {
            "title": "Mena",
            "movieid": "1",
            "movie_url": "videos\/mena.mp4",
            "buttons": [
                {
                    "left": 556,
                    "top": 231,
                    "start_time": 5.44,
                    "end_time": 6.76,
                    "width": 162,
                    "height": 73,
                    "buttonid": "1",
                    "label": "No"
                },
                {
                    "left": 200,
                    "top": 200,
                    "start_time": 5.56,
                    "end_time": 6.56,
                    "width": 162,
                    "height": 100,
                    "buttonid": "2",
                    "label": "Yes"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};  
  
for(var j = 0; j < json.movies.length; j++){
  for(a=0; a < json.movies[j].buttons.length; a++){
    var videobtns = $("<div class='video-btns'></div>");
    $(videobtns).html(json.movies[j].buttons[a].buttonid);
    $("#video-container").append(videobtns);
  }
}
```

```css
.video-btns {
  background: blue;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="video-container"></div>
```

Comment: Hii claudio , its perfectly displaying the button, but what about attributes like {top, left, width, heght, etc} right now u have provided them through css, I want those from json , is it possible?

Comment: @user9964622 you can pass those to jQuery `css()` method

Comment: Ye, i figured out now

Answer (score 0):

You have some miss variables errors. And some loops error, here is the solution

1. Your code is not working.
2. The reason you get 4 buttons is because you loop two times the array `movie[j].buttons.buttoid` which has two elements inside. so 2 times 2 = 4.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.6.1/flatpickr.css">
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="video-container">
        </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.6.1/flatpickr.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          var movies = [
                {
                    "title": "Mena",
                    "movieid": "1",
                    "movie_url": "videos\/mena.mp4",
                    "buttons": [
                        {
                            "left": 556,
                            "top": 231,
                            "start_time": 5.44,
                            "end_time": 6.76,
                            "width": 162,
                            "height": 73,
                            "buttonid": "1",
                            "label": "No"
                        },
                        {
                            "left": 200,
                            "top": 200,
                            "start_time": 5.56,
                            "end_time": 6.56,
                            "width": 162,
                            "height": 100,
                            "buttonid": "2",
                            "label": "Yes"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
            for(var j=0; j<movies.length; j++){
                var currMovie = movies[j]
                for(a=0; a< currMovie.buttons.length; a++){
                    var currBtn = currMovie.buttons[a];
                    var videobtns = $("<div class='video-btns'></div>")
                    $(videobtns).html(currBtn.buttonid + currBtn.label);
                    $("#video-container").append(videobtns);
                }
            }       
        });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the live examle

https://codepen.io/rollrodrig/pen/YoBJJX

Comment: @roll your soultion is good, I had many for loops , that is why it was generating 4 buttons

Comment: @charlietfl i added the reason.

Comment: @user9964622 just add what u need `currBtn.left`, `currBtn.top`, etc. This si basic, maybe you need to read little about json with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You have loop errors (and naming errors)
missing the index for the buttons:
data.movies[j].buttons[a]

```
var data = {
    "movies" : [
    {
        "title": "Mena",
        "movieid": "1",
        "movie_url": "videos\/mena.mp4",
        "buttons": [
    {
        "left": 556,
        "top": 231,
        "start_time": 5.44,
        "end_time": 6.76,
         "width": 162,
        "height": 73,
        "buttonid": "1",
        "label": "No"
    },
    {
        "left": 200,
        "top": 200,
        "start_time": 5.56,
        "end_time": 6.56,
        "width": 162,
        "height": 100,
        "buttonid": "2",
        "label": "Yes"
    }
]
}
]
}


for(var j=0; j<data.movies.length; j++){
    for(a=0; a< data.movies[j].buttons.length; a++){
        var videobtns = $("<div class='video-btns'>" + data.movies[j].buttons[a].buttonid + "</div>")
        $("#video-container").append(videobtns);
    }
}
```

Comment: The example I provided illustrates how to access the buttons loop. 

To access the other elements in the json object you can reference them the same way you reference the buttonid. for example: 

var btn = data.movies[j].buttons[a];  
var buttonId = btn.buttonid; 
var top= btn.top;

To format the buttons you can set the values using jquery (for example) 

$('"#" + btn.buttonId).css("top", btn.top);

or (this is not a good approach) you can set the values inline  by adding a style attribute to each button via the javascript loop. 

style="'top:" + btn.top + " left:" +  btn.left'"